# Counter for table labelling is wrong

Tags: tables, labels

I have a table and am trying to include a caption and label. The caption is printed but with the wrong number. It is my first table in the document, but latex uses the number of my Chapter (3.1) for the table.
I tried fixing it by manipulating the counter, but it will only change between 3.1 and 3.2.

This is my code:

```
\setcounter{table}{0} 
\begin{table}[h!]
\begin{tabu}to 0.8\textwidth { | X[c] || X[c] | X[c] | }
\hline
Measure & Min & Max \\ 
\hline \hline
One & 1 & 26 \\ 
\hline
Two & 6.353 & 2.2 \\ 
\hline
Three & 0 & 8.46 \\ 
\hline
Four & -16.86 & -2.94 \\ 
\hline
\end{tabu}
\caption{Statistics of indices}
\label{table:1}
\end{table}
```

Can somebody help?
I've been fighting with this table for hours and would really appreciate tips!

Comment: `Table 3.1` for the first table in chapter 3 is correct. What do you expect instead?

Comment: Just Table 1. 
I've seen the table numeration being independent from the chapters in other documents and thought that was the normal way to do it?
This sounds like there were several tables before this one

Comment: Add `\counterwithout{table}{chapter}` to your preamble.

Comment: @Bernard. Works perfectly, thank you! 
One last thing: I positioned the table with [h!], how do I put the caption right under it? It's somehow shifted to the left

Comment: @visitor: The normal way is `Table 3.1` and starting the counting new for each chapter.

Comment: Normally it is centred in its line. Add `\centering` just after `\begin{table}`.

Comment: @Bernard, I tried \centering, but it doesn't change anything. The caption is aligned with the text above the table.

Comment: Just got it. Made a mistake with the package needed for \centering. Thank you all for your quick help!

Comment: No package is require for `\centering`.